# File convertion not working inside a for loop

Tags: java, android

I need to ftp download and convert a file to a string, this way:

```
    public static boolean leArquivos(String inicioArquivo) {
    try {
        FTPClient mFtp = new FTPClient();
        mFtp.connect(FTPHOST, PORTA);
        mFtp.login(USUARIO, SENHA);
        FTPFile[] ftpFiles = mFtp.listFiles();
        int length = ftpFiles.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            String nome = ftpFiles[i].getName();
            String[] itens = nome.split("_");
            boolean isFile = ftpFiles[i].isFile();
            String arquivo_id = itens[0];
            if (isFile && (arquivo_id.equals(inicioArquivo))) {
                // the follow lines work if outside the for loop
                InputStream inStream = mFtp.retrieveFileStream(nome.toString());
                String arquivoLido = convertStreamToString(inStream);
                String[] arquivoLidoPartes = arquivoLido.split("#");
                Retorno.adicionaRegistro(nome, arquivoLidoPartes[0], arquivoLidoPartes[1], false);
            }
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

This gonna read a 'inicioArquivo_anything.txt' and put into a string.
FTP and Registro.adicionaRegistro works fine.
If I move the 4 lines that are inside the 'if' to outside the 'for' loop, it works for a single file.
I need perform the action for several files.

Sorry about bad english (and bad Java too)...

EDIT

Worked this way

The convertion code:

```
    private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is, FTPClient mFtp) throws IOException { // added the client
    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
        total.append(line);
    }
    r.close(); // close stream
    is.close(); // close stream
    mFtp.completePendingCommand(); 
    return total.toString();
}
```

And changed this:

```
String arquivoLido = convertStreamToString(inStream, mFtp);
inStream.close();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written in the API doc, you have to close the stream (after the conversion) and call the `completePendingCommand` method to finalize and check the status of the transfer :

[FTPClient.html#retrieveFileStream](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#retrieveFileStream%28java.lang.String%29)

And, in all you programs, the basics: don't forget to close the Streams !!

Comment: Can't up cause my low reputation. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Jairo Filho not a big deal ;-)

Comment: Voted up for closing first and then completing the pending command.